# How to set Layout Anchors depending on the length of the inscription?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to set UITableViewCell with two UILabels in the same line. For Example:
Tom Ford.
I know how to do it in hardcoded style, but how to do it depending on the length of the first name? I mean first names vary in length and I want to set the last name UILabel in the same length on the right same of the name UILabel. How to do it?

FirstName and LastName:

```
func setFirstnameLabel() {
    firstNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints                                               = false
    firstNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive                               = true
    firstNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 12).isActive                 = true
    firstNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive                                   = true
    firstNameLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive                                   = true
}

func setLastNameLabel() {
    lastNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints                                                = false
    lastNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive                                = true
    lastNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstNameLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive  = true
    lastNameLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive                                    = true
    lastNameLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive               = true
}
```

Comment: Constrain the leading edge of the second text field to the trailing edge of the first? Can you just combine the two names into one string and put that string in the one label?  It seems like that would be easier.

Comment: @Paulw11: Excellent idea! I did and it works and looks good. Thank you.